# Dexterity Content type with working copy (iterate) and workflow

Tags: workflow, plone, dexterity

I'm trying to apply Formal workflow to our custom made dexterity object. Buildout has     plone.app.versioningbehavior, collective.cmfeditionsdexteritycompat,  collective.dexteritydiff
plone.app.stagingbehavior, plone.app.referenceablebehavior.

What I'm finding is when I click checkout on it does create copy of object (copy_of_object) but ref to working copy(object) get corrupted?. At this moment if I get back to my working copy (object) its giving following error:

```
attributeError('getBRefs',) (Also, the following error occurred while attempting to render the standard error message, please see the event log for full details: getBRefs)
```

Any help would be great. here is my full trackback

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module grokcore.view.components, line 100, in __call__
  Module grokcore.view.components, line 104, in _render_template
  Module five.grok.components, line 134, in render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 113, in pt_render
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 742, in do_insertStructure_tal
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 218, in evaluateStructure
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
    - URL: file:c:\web\panda\buildout\src\rcseng.theme\rcseng\theme\skins\rcseng_theme_custom_templates\main_template.pt
    - Line 101, Column 12
    - Expression: <StringExpr u'plone.abovecontent'>
    - Names:
       {'args': (),
        'container': <Course at /riz/new-course>,
        'context': <Course at /riz/new-course>,
        'default': <object object at 0x0121E7F0>,
        'here': <Course at /riz/new-course>,
        'loop': {},
        'nothing': None,
        'options': {},
        'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x09DEED80>,
        'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8070/new-course/view>,
        'root': <Application at >,
        'static': <five.grok.components.ZopeTwoDirectoryResource object at 0x0989FD90>,
        'template': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0x0934B850>,
        'traverse_subpath': [],
        'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>,
        'view': <rcseng.contenttypes.course.Course_View object at 0x0989BCB0>,
        'views': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x09201BF0>}
  Module zope.contentprovider.tales, line 80, in __call__
  Module plone.app.viewletmanager.manager, line 154, in render
  Module plone.app.viewletmanager.manager, line 85, in render
  Module ilrt.formalworkflow.browser.info, line 9, in render
  Module plone.memoize.instance, line 51, in memogetter
  Module plone.app.iterate.browser.info, line 107, in working_copy
AttributeError: getBRefs
```

Comment: Post to dexterity development mailing list, you might get a better answer -- if you do, post it here.  Also, change your title from "workflow" to "working copy (iterate)" -- you will get more accurate interest.

Comment: Thanks, My membership is pending so once i'm in i will post there too.

Comment: It works fine if I create folder and created object inside. Site root level its giving this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine if I create folder and created object inside. Site root level its giving this error